# Multi Site, Multi admins, different contents, sharing content

Tags: permissions, content, multiple-sites

I want to use ExpressionEngine to build a website for a church. The church has several campuses across the USA. The church has a site and the campuses have their own mini-sites too.

Basically the church has a type of admin (A) and the campuses have another type of admin (B). B type admins can only access their content (of the campuses they own) and **A type admins can access all contents and administrate B type admins**. Also, B type admins can ask for content of their campus site to be on the church side (so sharing some content across websites).

Do you know of a way to do this? A plugin or so ? I'm not really familiar with EE's multi-site module.

Answer (score 3):

Multi Site Manager would work well for this.

- Each member group can be assigned to one or more sites in the network
- Super Admins can access all sites and settings.
- Content from other sites can be accessed by using the `site` parameter on any Channel Entries tag